# How to pipe SQL into R's dplyr?

Tags: sql, r, dplyr, r-dbi, dbplyr

I can use the following code in R to select distinct rows in any generic SQL database. I'd use `dplyr::distinct()` but it's not supported in SQL syntax. Anyways, this does indeed work:

```
dbGetQuery(database_name, 
           "SELECT t.* 
           FROM (SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY column_name ORDER BY column_name) AS SEQNUM 
           FROM table_name t
           ) t 
           WHERE SEQNUM = 1;")
```

I've been using it with success, but wonder how I can pipe that same SQL query after other dplyr steps, as opposed to just using it as a first step as shown above. This is best illustrated with an example:

```
distinct.df <- 
  left_join(sql_table_1, sql_table_2, by = "col5") %>% 
  sql("SELECT t.* 
      FROM (SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY column_name ORDER BY column_name) AS SEQNUM 
      FROM table_name t
      ) t 
      WHERE SEQNUM = 1;")
```

So I `dplyr::left_join()` two SQL tables, then I want to look at distinct rows, and keep all columns. Do I pipe SQL code into R as shown above (simply utilizing the `sql()` function)? And if so what would I use for the `table_name` on the line `FROM table_name t`?

In my first example I use the actual table name that I'm pulling from. It's too obvious! But in this case I am piping and am used to using the magrittr pronoun `.`  or sometimes the `.data` pronoun from rlang if I were in memory working in R without databases.

I'm in a SQL database though... so how do I handle this situation? How do I properly pipe my known working SQL into my R code (with a proper table name pronoun)? [dbplyr's reference page](https://dbplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/sql.html) is a good starting point but doesn't really answer this specific question.

Comment: @akrun. I'll give tidyquery a shot. Any idea how I can use a pronoun like `.` or `.data` to tell SQL to pipe the table above the `%>%` into the query? Instead of the dummy `table_name` I have listed in my code. https://github.com/ianmcook/tidyquery

Comment: May be thee limitations mentioned in the https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/queryparser/readme/README.html#current-limitations would also apply here

Comment: Is it possible for you to separate `dplyr` and `SQL` syntax ? So `df1 <- left_join(sql_table_1, sql_table_2, by = "col5")` and `df2 <-  sql("SELECT t.* 
      FROM (SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() ......` ?

Comment: In most SQL dialects distinct is supported. Try this: `library(sqldf); BOD2 <- rbind(BOD, BOD); sqldf("select distinct * from BOD2")` Also if you are using sqldf then you can do this:  `BOD2 %>% { sqldf("select distinct * from [.]") }  %>% mutate(demand = demand + 1)` illustrating using sql for both input and output.

Comment: I believe your SQL query can be written in dplyr syntax. Would you mind opening a new question? I'll post a reply regarding accessing the result of a dbplyr operation in a subsequent SQL query, which seems to be of interest on its own.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you are wanting to combine custom SQL code with auto-generated SQL code from `dbplyr`. For this it is important to distinguish between:

- `DBI::db*` commands - that execute the provided SQL on the database and return the result.
- `dbplyr` translation - where you work with a remote connection to a table

You can only combine these in certain ways. Below I have given several examples depending on your particular use case. All assume that `DISTINCT` is a command that is accepted in your specific SQL environment.

#### Reference examples that cover many of the different use cases

If you'll excuse some self-promotion, I recommend you take a look at my `dbplyr_helpers` GitHub repository ([here](https://github.com/simon-anasta/dbplyr_helpers)). This includes:

- `union_all` function that takes in two tables accessed via `dbplyr` and outputs a single table using some custom SQL code.
- `write_to_datebase` function that takes a table accessed via `dbplyr` and converts it to code that can be executed via `DBI::dbExecute`

#### Automatic piping

`dbplyr` automatically pipes your code into the next query for you when you are working with standard `dplyr` verbs for which there are SQL translations defined. So long as sql translations are defined you can chain together many pipes (I used 10 or more at once) with the (almost) only disadvantage being that the sql translated query gets difficult for a human to read.

For example, consider the following:

```r
library(dbplyr)
library(dplyr)

tmp_df = data.frame(col1 = c(1,2,3), col2 = c("a","b","c"))

df1 = tbl_lazy(tmp_df, con = simulate_postgres())
df2 = tbl_lazy(tmp_df, con = simulate_postgres())

df = left_join(df1, df2, by = "col1") %>%
  distinct()
```

When you then call `show_query(df)` R returns the following auto-generated SQL code:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM (

SELECT `LHS`.`col1` AS `col1`, `LHS`.`col2` AS `col2.x`, `RHS`.`col2` AS `col2.y`
FROM `df` AS `LHS`
LEFT JOIN `df` AS `RHS`
ON (`LHS`.`col1` = `RHS`.`col1`)

) `dbplyr_002`
```

But not as nicely formatted. Note that the initial command (left join) appears as a nested query, with a distinct in the outer query. Hence `df` is an R link to a remote database table defined by the above sql query.

#### Creating custom SQL functions

You can pipe `dbplyr` into custom SQL functions. Piping means that the thing being piped becomes the first argument of the receiving function.

```
custom_distinct <- function(df){
  db_connection <- df$src$con

  sql_query <- build_sql(con = db_connection,
                         "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM (\n",
                         sql_render(df),
                         ") AS nested_tbl"
  )
  return(tbl(db_connection, sql(sql_query)))
}

df = left_join(df1, df2, by = "col1") %>%
  custom_distinct()
```

When you then call `show_query(df)` R should return the following SQL code (I say 'should' because I can not get this working with simulated sql connections), but not as nicely formatted:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM (

SELECT `LHS`.`col1` AS `col1`, `LHS`.`col2` AS `col2.x`, `RHS`.`col2` AS `col2.y`
FROM `df` AS `LHS`
LEFT JOIN `df` AS `RHS`
ON (`LHS`.`col1` = `RHS`.`col1`)

) nested_tbl
```

As with the previous example, `df` is an R link to a remote database table defined by the above sql query.

#### Converting dbplyr to DBI

You can take the code from an existing `dbplyr` remote table and convert it to a string that can be executed using `DBI::db*`.

As another way of writing a distinct query:

```r
df1 = tbl_lazy(tmp_df, con = simulate_postgres())
df2 = tbl_lazy(tmp_df, con = simulate_postgres())

df = left_join(df1, df2, by = "col1")

custom_distinct2 = paste0("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM (",
                          as.character(sql_render(df)),
                          ") AS nested_table")

local_table =   dbGetQuery(db_connection, custom_distinct2)
```

Which will return a local R dataframe with the equivalent sql command as per the previous examples.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to do custom SQL processing on the result of a dbplyr operation, it may be useful to `compute()` first, which creates a new table (temporary or permanent) with the result set on the database. The reprex below shows how to access the name of the newly generated table if you rely on autogeneration. (Note that this relies on dbplyr internals and is subject to change without notice -- perhaps it's better to name the table explicitly.) Then, use `dbGetQuery()` as usual.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(dbplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dbplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:dplyr':
#> 
#>     ident, sql

lazy_query <-
  memdb_frame(a = 1:3) %>%
  mutate(b = a + 1) %>%
  summarize(c = sum(a * b, na.rm = TRUE))

lazy_query
#> # Source:   lazy query [?? x 1]
#> # Database: sqlite 3.30.1 [:memory:]
#>       c
#>   <dbl>
#> 1    20

lazy_query_computed <-
  lazy_query %>%
  compute()

lazy_query_computed
#> # Source:   table<dbplyr_002> [?? x 1]
#> # Database: sqlite 3.30.1 [:memory:]
#>       c
#>   <dbl>
#> 1    20
lazy_query_computed$ops$x
#> <IDENT> dbplyr_002
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

If your SQL dialect supports [CTE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_and_recursive_queries_in_SQL#Common_table_expression)s, you could also extract the query string and use this as part of a custom SQL, perhaps similarly to Simon's suggestion.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(dbplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dbplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:dplyr':
#> 
#>     ident, sql

lazy_query <-
  memdb_frame(a = 1:3) %>%
  mutate(b = a + 1) %>%
  summarize(c = sum(a * b, na.rm = TRUE))

sql <-
  lazy_query %>%
  sql_render()

cte_sql <-
  paste0(
    "WITH my_result AS (", sql, ") ",
    "SELECT c + 1 AS d FROM my_result"
  )

cte_sql
#> [1] "WITH my_result AS (SELECT SUM(`a` * `b`) AS `c`\nFROM (SELECT `a`, `a` + 1.0 AS `b`\nFROM `dbplyr_001`)) SELECT c + 1 AS d FROM my_result"

DBI::dbGetQuery(
  lazy_query$src$con,
  cte_sql
)
#>    d
#> 1 21
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>